# Why does Error 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module ' when I try to use ES Modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package.json, es6-modules

When I try to use ES Modules for my existing React app  (*React v16.13.1 with Node v14.15.4 and Webpack 5* ) with webpack as per the required procedure ([ref](https://medium.com/digio-australia/migrating-an-npm-package-to-use-es-modules-d59877963d61))
I run into this error : `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:/Users/....path/webpack.apps.config.js` [image]
If I change my `webpack.apps.config.js` to have all dependencies added using `import` statements as per the error to this :

```
import  fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import CssMinimizerPlugin from 'css-minimizer-webpack-plugin';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';
```

I run into this: `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`[image]

They seem contradicting to me as I have been juggling between `require()` and `module.exports` VS `import` and `export` syntaxes.
Could someone suggest if and what would be the correct way to insert ESModules for `react` and `react-dom` ?

Note: I have used `"type" : "module"` in `package.json`
and all other changes as per the ref link attached above.

Edit: Even if I convert my `webpack.config.js` to `webpack.config.cjs` and change the `imports` to `require()` and `module.exports` to `export` as suggested as possible fix , I still get a Segmentation Fault issue. Is this because ES Modules for webpack is an [experimental feature](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12308#issuecomment-753643801)?   [image]

Comment: `webpack.apps.config.js` is not a module. It's not part of your code, in which you might use ES6 modules, it's a configuration file of your toolchain.

Comment: The error means one of the modules you are trying to import is an ES module which you MUST use `import` to, well, import. You are right to use `require`. Are you sure all of the modules you are using are actually for `webpack`? Unless some one mess it up `webpack` plugins should never be ES modules.